# set preview image for Google drive folder link sharing

Tags: google-drive, links, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Drive folder with link sharing turned on. I want to set a preview image, for social media.

Right now, it uses a low resolution Google Drive logo expanded to fit the preview image size, which makes it look pixelated.

Is there a way to control what image appears?

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out the [tour] and [ask].